# Get WordPress post content by post id

Tags: posts

How can I get WordPress post content by post id?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Simple as it gets

```
$my_postid = 12;//This is page id or post id
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
```

Comment: Shorthand for specific field: `$content = get_post_field('post_content', $my_postid);`

Comment: @Bainternet I'm just curious here... what is the part `$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);` do? what's the purpose of it there?

Comment: @AverageJoe its basic search and replace. When using the_content() the content is filtered. Since in the above example the content was directly retrieved, the author has used the search and replace to make it safe.

Comment: maybe you also need do_shortcode() like `$content = do_shortcode(get_post_field('post_content', $my_postid));`

Comment: Is there anyway to preserve the "more_link"?

Answer (score 156):

```
echo get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
```

Comment: better to do it like `echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post_id));`. For example when using qTranslate, your solution would not be enough.

Comment: This is the best answer if the scope is to get the post content as it is in the WordPress edit page.

Comment: Without the code from @KarelAttl line breaks where missing. With the apply_filters code it worked perfectly.

Comment: `apply_filters` is a good option, but wasn't right for my current purpose. It's good to have both options.

Answer (score 49):

Another way to get a WordPress post content by post id is:

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $my_postid));
```

---

To complete this answer I have also added method 01 and method 02 to this answer.

Method 01 (credit goes to [bainternet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/9668/106350)):

```
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
```

Method 02 (credit goes to [realmag777](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67255/106350)):

```
$content = get_post_field('post_content', $my_postid);
```

Method 03:

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $my_postid));
```

Read the *[What is the best / efficient way to get WordPress content by post id and why?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/245692/what-is-the-best-efficient-way-to-get-wordpress-content-by-post-id-and-why)* question to get an idea about which one you should use from the above three.

Answer (score 6):

Starting from wordpress 5.2.0,

We can now use post object or post id `get_the_content` function.

We can also pass *$more_link_text* and *$strip_teaser*

```
get_the_content( string $more_link_text = null, bool $strip_teaser = false, WP_Post|object|int $post = null )
```

We can use it along with `apply_filters` like below to get all filters of `the_content`

```
apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content(null, false, $post_id)),
```

[Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/)

Answer (score -5):

If you need more than one post, use [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). It leaves the main query alone and returns an array of posts that's easy to loop over.

Comment: This answer misunderstands the question