# Why There Is No "get content by ID" Function

Tags: functions, customization, core, core-modifications

When i need to get content of a post with ID, I'm always using this function :

```
function getContentByID($id)
{
//http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9667/get-wordpress-post-content-by-post-id
$content_post = get_post($id);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
return $content;
}
```

Can you tell me, why there isn't any core function for this ? There are functions like get_the_title($id), get_the_category($id) ...

Comment: If you'd like to see something in core, [you're free to submit a patch](http://codex.wordpress.org/User:HEngel/How_To_Become_A_WordPress_Developer).

Answer (score 2):

There is [`get_post_field()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field), which is very, very close to your proposed solution.

```
$content = get_post_field('post_content',$your_post_id);
```

Frankly, I think WordPress already suffers from helper function overload, but there you go.