# Get content of publish box

Tags: admin, metabox, publish

is there any way how to safely get content of the publish box?
[image]

For example via some hook or filter? I wasn't able to find anything.

I need to place in in some different place.

Comment: You can get the content by post id, check [This thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9667/get-wordpress-post-content-by-post-id)

Comment: It's not what I want. I edited the question so it's more clear what I try to do.

Comment: Where do you want to move the submit metabox?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'show_current_filter' );
add_action( 'post_submitbox_start', 'show_current_filter' );

function show_current_filter()
{
    $post = get_post();

    print '<pre>' .  $post->ID . ' : ' . current_filter() . '</pre>';
}
```

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_submitbox_misc_actions
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_submitbox_start/

Comment: ok but how this helps me getting the content of the whole publish box?

Comment: What do you need to do? If you want the contents can't you just target it with jQuery?

Comment: You wanted a hook and the above will give you a hook to add something. If you just need a publish button then make a mata box and write you're own publish button. Describing your end goal could net you a much more fruitful answer.