# How to get unmodified post content?

Tags: posts, content, post-content

How do you get the unmodified post content?

It seems WordPress modifies the post content. It changes the HTML by adding or removing from it.

This post is different from this post:

[Get WordPress post content by post id](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/9667/29247)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the original content is unmodified if I access it like this:

```
 echo $post->post_content;
```

And I do not save the post in the editor and do not use the visual editor.

This is using WordPress 5.4.2.